# Maximum Likelihood Estimator exercise - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $X_1$, ... , $X_2$ be a sample from the distribution whose probability density function is:

$f(x)=$ $\frac{1}{3}*e^{-\frac{1}{3}*(x-\theta),}\atop{0,}$ $x\geq\theta\atop{x<\theta}$

*Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$*

Following is my attempt to find the MLE (I could not get the image to work):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CZuy.jpg

I use this guy's method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z582V53dfr8

I get an answer depending on $n$ which does not make sense to me. The answer my teacher gave was $\min(x_i)$, but his explanation used $\arg$ which I do not understand.

Am I using a wrong method? Have I simply made an error somewhere? Do you know another method I can use?

Edit: As far as I can see, no matter how I do the logarithmic operations, i will always only get an expression of $n$ after differentiating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating is not the correct approach here. The problem is that each $f(x_i; \theta)$ depends discontinuously on $\theta$: they jump from $1/3$ when $\theta$ equals $x_i$ to $0$ when $\theta$ is greater than $x_i$. The likelihood function $L(x_1, \dots, x_n ; \theta)$, being a product of the $f(x_i; \theta)$'s, is not a differentiable function of $\theta$ either.

Instead, let's try to solve this using common sense! The question we should ask ourselves is: which value of $\theta$ maximises the likelihood of observing the values $x_1, \dots, x_n$ that we obtained in the sample? In other words, which value of $\theta$ maximises $L(x_1, \dots, x_n; \theta) = f(x_1;\theta) \times \dots \times f(x_n; \theta)$?

First of all, we should notice that the "best" value of theta cannot be greater than any of the $x_i$'s. If $\theta$ is greater than a particular $x_i$, then $f(x_i, \theta)$ would be zero, so the likelihood $L(x_1, \dots, x_n; \theta)$ would also be zero, hence this value of $\theta$ can't give the highest possible likelihood.

On the other hand, suppose that there is some "breathing space" between your choice of $\theta$ and the smallest of the $x_i$'s. This value of $\theta$ can't be the best choice either. If you increase $\theta$ by a tiny amount, then the new $\theta$ will still be smaller than all of the $x_i$'s, and each of the $f(x_i; \theta)$'s, and hence also $L(x_1, \dots, x_n; \theta)$, will be greater than what they were originally, hence the original $\theta$ couldn't have given the highest possible likelihood.

The conclusion is that the value of $\theta$ that gives the largest likelihood $L(x_1, \dots, x_n; \theta)$ is precisely equal to the smallest of the $x_i$'s. And that is the answer given by your teacher.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense, actually. Is there a general method to calculate this, or is it always about looking at it logically?

Comment: @user102937 Nine times out of ten, the likelihood function is differentiable, and you're fine with the differentiation method!

Comment: Perhaps this is worth pointing out explicitly: If the support of the random variable depends on the parameter, be careful! Recall that, back in calculus, we were told to look at the end points of the interval when we are looking for the max/min.